# Why is MediaPlayer calling IllegalStateException when I call release()?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, illegalstateexception

I have an `Activity` in which there's a `MediaPlayer` that, after about 150 plays, puts up a system message saying "Video couldn't be played".  A force restart of the app resets this problem for another 150 plays.

I'm assuming that this is a memory leak of some kind, though I'm entirely unclear as to what would be leaking, and also the simptoms don't align with how much memory Android allots my app. The video is about 3mb, so, if I'm leaking that much at every play the implication would be that my app has access to 450mb of memory which we know isn't true.

In any event, I'm trying to see if I can manually release the video somehow, but I'm getting an `IllegalStateException` when I call release on the `MediaPlayer` that is passed into my `onCompletion` callback.

My code looks like this:

```
VideoView vv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.movie);
Uri videoURI = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/video_in" );
vv.setVideoURI(videoURI);
vv.start();
vv.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {         
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getPackageName() + ".SCENE_2");               
        startActivity(i);
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();//here the exception is raised
        finish();
    }
});
```

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#Valid_and_Invalid_States) seems to imply that there's no state in which you can't call release on a `MediaPlayer`, so, I'm stumped. I'm in JellyBean, in case that makes any difference.

Comment: Only thing that comes to mind is calling release before you start another activity, but i havent really studied MediaPlayer that well to know why that should interfere, it might be worth trying though.

Comment: I gave that a whirl before I posted. It doesn't appear to have anything to do with either the start of the next activity or the finish call right after.  In other threads I've read the `release` is only done if mp.isPlaying() is true, which in my case it's not, but why would it have to be playing to be releasable? Makes no sense.

Comment: The more i read on this subject, the more intrigued i get. Can you provide the full stack trace, also if it has already completed you shouldn't need to call `stop()` just `release()` would do it.  You said that it throws `IllegalStateException` can you check what state is the MediaPlayer in(I know it should be stopped or PlaybackCompleted, but it would be good to know wich one it thinks it is in)?

Comment: By looking at the source code from VideoView it seems you can call stopPlayback on you VideoView Object and that should do the clean up. You can check the source here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/VideoView.java

Comment: I believe your `IllegalStateException` is coming from `mp.stop` and not `mp.release`. Please refer to this link: http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/media/jni/android_media_MediaPlayer.cpp#357 . The issue when you are stopping the `MediaPlayer`, the `MediaPlayer` is already `NULL`.

Comment: As Ganesh said, it's probably not the release call that is throwing the exception. I recommend wrapping the code in your onCompletionListener on a try/catch block in order to confirm which line is throwing the exception.

Comment: It's the release().  The stop was actually put there as part of my hunt for solutions.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel Could you specify the version of Android you are working on?

Comment: I'm running Jellybean